# How to make something like AdCloseGold?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm frequently dealing with websites that open a bunch of new tabs with ads and I'm tired of it.

A while back I discovered `AdCloseGold` which is a Chrome extension that automatically closes all tabs that open a specified URL and I've happily used it for a while now.

Unfortunately, `AdCloseGold` has a few shortcomings:

1) No wildcards in the url

2) A limited amount of urls one can ad (because it stores the data in a Google account)

3) Doesn't close blank pages or page not found.

4) Doesn't have a button or something that says "add THIS page to auto close", meaning you have to copy and paste all urls manually into the list.

5) Doesn't provide any prewritten list of urls.

Recently I've started using the hosts file, redirecting urls to a nonsense address and then close that address through AdCloseGold, meaning I need just one address to auto close, but that has quite some problems as well, because the hosts file requires the full url, i.e. adding xyz.com to the hosts file doesn't redirect abc.xyz.com.

Furthermore, I do not really want to redirect all of these urls permanently but rather only in Chrome, so I can still access those pages through Firefox or IE.

I'm a (hobby) coder and I don't mind the work, I consider it more fun than work, but I only have some rudimentary knowledge of how to make a Chrome extension.

So the question is: Does a Chrome extension like an advanced AdCloseGold already exist and if not (I couldn't find any) where would I find a detailed enough tutorial for Chrome extensions, where I could learn this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of Ad Close Gold here. I'm aware of the shortcoming you mentioned in your question. I've really wanted to add those to the add-on but never really can find the time to do so. I first created the add-on just for myself and it was fine for me. I thought I'd share the add-on with everyone since, even till this day, I cannot find any add-on that will auto-close tabs for me.

I have the source code for the add-on on github: https://github.com/mukunku/Ad-Close-Gold

Feel free to fork the repository and make any changes. You can create a separate add-on or merge the code back to my project if you like. If you merge the code back to mine, I can release it as a new version (And give you credit of course).

P.S. Wild cards are technically supported. If you use a regular expression as the URL and enable the **IsRegEx** option, it will work.

For example: www.ali.*.com
This will match all of the following:

- [www.aliexpress.com](http://www.aliexpress.com)
- [www.aliother.com](http://www.aliother.com)
- [www.ali.com](http://www.ali.com)